# Does Gill's statement on ragged right in books still hold true today?

Tags: typesetting

Eric Gill, in an *Essay on Typography* writes:

> But even spacing is of more importance typographically than equal length. Even spacing is a great assistance to easy reading; hence its pleasantness, for the eye is not vexed by the roughness, jerkiness, restlessness and spottiness which uneven spacing entails, even if such things be reduced to a minimum by careful setting. It may be laid down that even spacing is in itself desirable, that uneven length of lines is not in itself desirable, that both apparently even spacing and equal length of lines may be obtained when the measure allows of over fifteen words to the line, but that the best length for reading is not more than 12 words, and that therefore it is better to sacrifice actual equality of length rather than evenness of spacing

However, when Gill was writing, text was hand set with a composing stick and spacing with the aid of algorithms (like that in TeX or commercial software) was unimaginable.  Do his observations still carry weight in today's graphic design community, or has technology advanced sufficiently that uneven spacing can be done without vexing the eye with ‘roughness, jerkiness, restlessness, and spottiness’?

Comment: Surely this is something that one would have to measure. But alas graphic design isnt a terribly scientific field so only a few datapoints gave been gathered. Sounds like a good candidate for a research topic.

Comment: I agree with @joojaa that this should be measured before one can say anything meaningful about it. I would guess that it's hard to isolate the issue in a scientific test. So many factors affect readability. And there is also another aspect which is how *appealing* a design looks. This can sometimes work against readability, but can perhaps increase the amount of people who actually *wants* to read. The question is sometimes how important readability is. Are you making an emergency manual for astronauts in distress or a fancy magazine for hipsters? 